# C# Chatbot case contains

Tags: c#, chatbot

I want to make a chatbot with C# (Microsoft Visual Studio).

Could you tell me how to make a case.contains? For example: If case contains "How are you" (without and with capital) or "Are you
   ok ?" then string reponseA = "I'm good thanks and you ?"

```
private void QuestionBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            string chat = QuestionBox.Text; // la notion string défini le nom d'une action
            string utisateur = "Vous :  "; // défini le utilisateur par "Vous :"
            string bot = "Robot : "; // défini le bot par "Robot :"
            ChatBox.Items.Add(utisateur + chat); // ajoute le nom "Vous" + la question posée en appyant sur Entrée
            QuestionBox.Clear(); // ajoute le message sur la ChatBox et efface la QuestionBox

            switch (chat)
            {
                case ase "Hello how are you ?: // question posée par l'utilisateur
                    string reponseA = "I'm good thanks and you ?"; // réponse donnée par Robot
                    ChatBox.Items.Add(bot + reponseA); // ajout la réponse à la ChatBox                         
                    break;
```

Comment: First you case is invalid and missing a closing quote. To make it case insensitive either uppercase or lowercase your input `chat` and check with upper/lower case strings.

Answer (score 1):

thanks to C# 7 you can do that like this:

```
// You should probably use ToLower before
switch (chat)
{
    case chat when chat.Contains("how are you?"):

        break;
}
```

Although this works fine and is perfectly what you're looking for, you might want to use another approach, something like stored commands/answers or something because after a while you'll have a really big switch/case and it's not gonna be fun to debug/add/etc..

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get rid from your `switch` statement at all and do it without hardcoding chat messages.
You can put expected questions from user into external text file like this:

> How are you
>   I'm good thanks and you ?
>   Are you ok ?
>   I'm good thanks and you ?

first line is question, second is response to user and so on.
After that read this file (in class constructor, for example) with this code:

```
private Dictionary<string, string> qa;

public YourClassConstructor()
{
  this.qa = File.ReadLines("qa.txt")
      .Select((line, index) => new {line, index})
      .GroupBy(x => x.index / 2)
      .ToDictionary(g => g.First().line.ToLower(), g => g.Last().line);
}
```

Now in `QuestionBox_KeyDown` you can simply check if message is known:

```
string reponseA = qa.ContainsKey(chat.ToLower())
            ? qa[chat.ToLower()]
            : "Unknown request";
```

If you need a partial match you can replace above code with this cycle:

```
foreach (var kv in qa)
{
    if (kv.Key.Contains(chat.ToLower()))
    {
        reponseA = kv.Value;
        break;
    }
}
```